# Как конвертировать обычную str дату в timestamp?

Tags: python, python-2.x, datetime, timestamp

```
import time
from datetime import datetime

d = datetime.strptime("25.05.2017 15:56:53", "%d.%m.%Y %H:%M:%S").strftime("%s")
print d
```

Этот код выдает ошибку

```
ValueError: Invalid format string
```

Как сделать так что бы всё работало?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Кусок `datetime.strptime("25.05.2017 15:56:53", "%d.%m.%Y %H:%M:%S")` вполне успешно работает, и преобразовывает текстовое представление в объект `datetime` вида `datetime.datetime(2017, 5, 25, 15, 56, 53)`
2. По поводу ошибки. Вот здесь есть описание "тэгов" форматирования для методов `strftime()` и `strptime()`: [**strftime() and strptime() Behavior**](https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#strftime-strptime-behavior). В приведенной там таблице нет `%s`, которое вы пытаетесь использовать для форматирования. Отсюда ошибка.
3. Чтобы конвертировать объект `datetime` в `timestamp`, можно воспользоваться следующим кодом:

   ```
   import time
   from datetime import datetime

   d = datetime.strptime("25.05.2017 15:56:53", "%d.%m.%Y %H:%M:%S")
   ts = time.mktime(d.timetuple())
   print ts  # 1495717013.0
   ```

Comment: ЕМНИП, mktime опирается на системный часовой пояс?

Comment: @andreymal, в доках написано, что `mktime()` обратна `localtime()`. `time.localtime()` возвращает время согласно системному часовому поясу, в отличие от `time.gmtime()` (которая возвращает время по UTC). Ну и по идее `mktime()` вернет количество секунд, прошедших с `01.01.1970 00:00:00` по UTC с учетом системного часового пояса.